# Empty attribute selector not working in Edge browser

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I'm using a specific version of Edge where the empty attribute selector is not working (more information [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13197805/))

My selector looks like this:

```
[ct-validation]:not([ct-validation=""]) {
  border-color: red;
}
```

The `ct-validation` attribute contains an error message. If the error message exists, then a red border is applied to the element. This works fine in all browsers except for Edge (40.15063.0.0). Upgrading is not an option due to Corporate IT restrictions :(

Is there a different way to check that an attribute is empty with using CSS **only**?

Answer (score 0):

<s>I can't confirm this works in actual Edge browser, but</s>  
Overriding the user agent in chrome dev tools & edge dev tools produces desired results with simply cascading the styles down:

User agent for reference: 
*Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063*

Notice the different examples it covers:

```css
[ct-validation] {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
}

[ct-validation=""] {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div ct-validation="">bad</div>
<div ct-validation="    ">bad</div>
<div ct-validation=>bad</div>
<div ct-validation>bad</div>
<div ct-validation="abc">good</div>
```

---

Edit: tested the same thing in Edge dev tools overriding the user agent to v15.15063

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but notice there is a :not. So the error css should only appear when there IS a value in ct-validation. ct-validation could contain any validation message so its not possible to add something like [ct-validation="add your phone number"] either.